# RDL report as an email attachment with SQL email sending

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

I need to send a recurring report to subscribed users.
I use [this example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Automated-Email-Notifications-using-SQL-Server-Job-Schedular.aspx) to send emails.

SQL to send email,

```
 DECLARE
@out_desc VARCHAR(1000),
@out_mesg VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20),
@birthdate datetime,
@email NVARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE C1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT [name], [birthdate], [email]
FROM Customers

OPEN C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
@name, @birthdate, @email
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
      IF DATEPART(DAY,@birthdate) = DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())
      AND DATEPART(MONTH,@birthdate) = DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())
      BEGIN
            SET @body = '<b>Happy Birthday ' + @name +
            '</b><br />Many happy returns of the day'
            + '<br /><br />Customer Relationship Department'
            EXEC sp_send_mail   --THIS IS THE SP WHICH SEND EMAILS
            sender@abc.com',
            'xxxxxxx',
            @email,
            'Birthday Wishes',
            @body,
            'htmlbody',
            @output_mesg = @out_mesg output,
            @output_desc = @out_desc output

            PRINT @out_mesg
            PRINT @out_desc
      END
      FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
      @name, @birthdate, @email
END
CLOSE C1
DEALLOCATE C1
```

I need to generate an attachment to the email using an RDL report. I have a "BirthdayAlert.rdl" in the report server. How can I get this report to the attachment?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution with steps for your problem.

1) Deploy this report on server.
2) Subscribe this report for automatic execution at schedule intervals.
3) Job will be created.
4) write sql procedure for this job to execute at your intervals. This sql should do the following things.
       a) Execute report job 
       b) pdf / docx  file will be generated on the server at the location you specified.
       c) with the help of senddbmail , attach this file and send it to the user .

Hope you got the answer for your query.

Comment: Can you share a code sample for PDF/Excel creation from SQL using a RDL report?